# Unable to take ScreenShot with TestNG using onTestFailure

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

**My Listener Class Code**

```
package com.test.automation.uiAuotmation.customListner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import com.test.automation.uiAuotmation.testBase.TestBase;

public class Listener extends TestBase implements ITestListener {

public void onFinish(ITestContext arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStart(ITestContext arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yy_hh_mm_ss");

    String methodName = result.getName();

    if (!result.isSuccess()) {

        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        String reportDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getAbsolutePath()
                + "/src/main/java/com/test/automation/uiAutomation/";

        File destFile = new File((String) reportDirectory + "/failure_screenshots/" + methodName + "_"
                + formater.format(calendar.getTime()) + ".png");

        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Reporter.log("<a href='" + destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'> <img src='" + destFile.getAbsolutePath()
                + "' height='100' width='100'/> </a>");

    }

}

private void File(String property) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onTestStart(ITestResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

**My Test Base Code**

```
package com.test.automation.uiAuotmation.testBase;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import com.test.automation.uiAuotmation.excelReader.Excel_Reader;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class TestBase {

public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestBase.class.getName());

public static WebDriver driver;
public String Browser = "Firefox";
public String url = "http://automationpractice.com/index.php";
Excel_Reader excel;

public void init() {
    selectBrowser(Browser);
    selectURL(url);
    String log4jConfPath = "log4j.properties";
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
}

public void selectBrowser(String Browser) {
    if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Drivers/geckodriver.exe");
        log.info("Creating object of Browser" + Browser);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    else if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}

public void selectURL(String url) {
    log.info("Navigating to" + url);
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

**My TestCase Code**

```
package com.test.automation.uiAuotmation.homepage;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.test.automation.uiAuotmation.testBase.TestBase;
import com.test.automation.uiAuotmation.uiActions.HomePage;

public class TC002_VerifyRegistration extends TestBase {

HomePage homepage;

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
    init();
}

@Test
public void verifyRegistration() {
    homepage = new HomePage(driver);
    homepage.register("dig101@gmail.com", "fname", "lname", "digi11", "fname", "lname", "dell", "manyata park",
            "Florida", "00000", "12345", "aliasaddress");
    Assert.assertEquals("Welcome to your account. Here you can manage all of your personal information and orders.",
            homepage.registrationSuccess());
}
@AfterTest
public void endTest() {
    //driver.quit();
       }
    }
```

I am purposely failing the testcase by changing the object Identification. As expected my test case fails with(No SuchElementException). Howeve, My TestNg fails to take the screen shot during when the test case fails. I am unable to figure out where is the mistake. 
Above you can find the code for ITestListener, My Testbase Code and My Testcases.

Comment: I can't see where you're failing your test.

Comment: How have you registered this listener? In testng.xml or with annotation? Also you are better off extending  TestListenerAdapter instead of ITestListener. TestListenerAdapter provides empty methods so your code is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your listener class is properly setup to handle the events. Please go through the following link for setting it up
[TestNg Listeners](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-listeners/)

After that put a debug point in onTestFailure function of the listener and check if the control reached till that point.

Another was of capturing snapshots at failures is to place the snapshot capture logic in @AfterTest method and set it to always run i.e

```
@AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
public void endTest() {
    //snapshot logic
}
```

Comment: HI, I went through the link you provided. I am using the second method for  Listener tag in TestNG xml  for listening my class. I believe the setup is handled correctly.   As you suggested i put a break point and it was not hitting the onTestFailure method ... Any help where is the mistake thanks

Comment: I just used the first method as per the link  [link]( http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-listeners/)... i.e Implement TestNG Listener to your test class

Comment: Yes, But Listener tag in TestNG xml didnt work. .. I don't know where is the mistake may be I am assuming  I need use the recent version of TestNG I am using 6.10

Comment: Yes play with it, you will be able to figure it out :)